Обновление информации в json-server
У меня имеется файл db.json, на основе которого создаётся json-server, который содержит информацию о пациентах:
"patients": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "status": "bad",
            "lastName": "Николаев",
            "firstName": "Пётр",
            "surname": "Иванович",
            "spot": {
                "department": "Therapy",
                "house": "1",
                "floor": "2",
                "ward": "1",
                "bed": "1"
            },
            "dossier": {
                "dateOfBirth": "25.11.1980",
                "previousDiseases": [],
                "contradictions": [
                    "Аллергия на цитрусы"
                ]
            },
            "assignments": [
                {
                    "titles": ["Трамадол 500 мг", "Фенкарол 25 мг"],
                    "urgent": true
                },
                {
                    "titles": ["МРТ"],
                    "urgent": false
                },
                {
                    "titles": ["Подготовка к операции"],
                    "urgent": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

Я пытаюсь добавить в массив assignments запись при помощи RTK Query:
export const patientAPI = createApi({
    reducerPath: "patient",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: "http://localhost:3001/patients"}),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        addAssignment: builder.mutation({
            query: ({id, assignment}) => ({
              url: `/${id}/assignments`,
              method: 'POST',
              body: assignment
            })
        })
    })

Но при попытке добавления получаю следующую ошибку:
POST http://localhost:3001/patients/0/assignments 404 (Not Found)
Как я могу изменять массив assignments у пациента, как можно изменить mutation у patientAPI, чтобы он мог добавлять записи в объект конкретного пациента?
